# Access all children component of a React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have react component A which renders a table. Data for one of the columns in the table is rendered through another component B, so `<B/>` is child of `<A/>`. I want to perform some action on `<B/>` whenever user clicks anywhere on the page. This click event listener is defined inside `A`. How can I loop through all `<B/>s` from inside class `A`? My component structure is something like this:

```
class A extends React.Component {
   <B/>
   <B/>
   <B/>
   <B/>
};
```

I came across `React.Children.forEach`, but that is useful when children are passed as props via `this.props.children`; i.e. when the code is something like this:

```
<A>some markup</A>
```

Comment: Can you describe what kind of action you want to perform on component B and if you are passing any property to them? In order to add Bs component, how are you doing that? Maybe you have an array or another structure that holds the data and you are iterating through it or you are doing it just explicitly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I figured it out. I gave `ref` to each `<B/>`, and stored it in an array:

```
class A extends React.Component {
  collectRefs = [];
  <B ref={b => {this.collectRefs.push(b)}}/>
  <B ref={b => {this.collectRefs.push(b)}}/>
  <B ref={b => {this.collectRefs.push(b)}}/>

  for(const b of collectRefs) {
    // do stuff
  }
}
```

Comment: Just as long as you're aware of the downsides of using a ref in React.  the components become uncontrolledComponents, and then the props listeners stop working and you're responsible for the lifecycle.  That's my understanding anyway

Answer (score 4):

```
const childrenProps = React.Children.map(this.props.children,
 (child) => React.cloneElement(child, {
    data : this.state,
    method : this.method.bind(this)
   // here you can pass state or method of parent component to child components
 }));

  // to access you can use this.props.data or this.props.method in child component
```

you need to pass this {childrenProps} which include all child components.